Two ways to define the group law on an elliptic curve
I know two ways to look at the group structure on an elliptic curve (over a complex field). On one hand, the complex torus $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^2$ using the Weierstrass $\wp$-function. This creates a bijection between $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ and the (closed) points of the elliptic curve in the projective plane, allowing the natural quotient abelian group structure on $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ to be imposed on the elliptic curve. On the other hand, the set of closed points bijects to the degree zero subgroup of the Picard group as $P \mapsto P - P_0$ where $P_0$ is the inflection point. Injectivity follows from the fact that if two distinct points are linearly equivalent, then the curve is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. It is surjective because essentially $(P - P_0) + (Q - P_0) \sim T - P_0$ where $P, Q, R$ are colinear and $R, P_0, T$ are colinear in $\mathbb{P}^2$, which also describes the group structure in elementary way.
Now, by the addition theorem of Weierstrass $\wp$-function, two group laws are same. I'm curious if this is purely a coincidence. I think both structures are both very natural but their constructions look very different, so I wonder if there could be another explanation for why these two groups are isomorphic, without relying on addition theorem. I was thinking about considering the embedding with line bundles but it didn't work well.
More generally, is there an example where, for a (maybe algebraically closed) field $k$, and some discrete subgroup $G$, $k/G$ embeds into some projective space thus being a dimension one abelian variety? And if so, does it have some relation with its Picard group?

They are two different ways of describing what is called the Jacobian variety: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_variety

(This means that the group law in both cases is describing the tensor product of line bundles, in different ways. Elliptic curves have this very funny property that they are isomorphic to their own Jacobian varieties, and this is not true for curves of higher genus $g$, where the Jacobian variety is an abelian variety of complex dimension $g$.)
